# Current sensing at μA accuracy and ADC nonlinearity

Tags: adc, design, current-measurement

**Project context** 
A battery-operated positioning device sends location information through GSM at regular intervals. Between the fixes, the device is in low-power mode. The battery is supposed to last months or even years, hence the importance of power consumption. I need to design a high-side current monitor to measure the current drawn from the battery and graph it on a computer, so that we can optimize the frequency of fixes vs power consumption.

**Measurement requirements** 
(renegociated after the first draft, which was IMO unrealistic)

- range 0 A to 1.5 A
- resolution <= 1 μA
- accuracy <= 1 μA
- output data rate >= 1 kHz

**Hardware requirements**

- high-side current shunt, the voltage across the resistor is measured by an INA
- the INA's output voltage is converted by ten 32-bit ADC in parallel, each one sampling at 100 Hz
- the ADC data is retrieved by an MCU, which sends the data through USB
- the measurement device has its own battery and the USB is isolated
- the PCB is supposed to be temperature-regulated, to minimize the thermal effects on the gain and offsets

**Hardware selection**
The shunt resistor is a four-terminal Vishay 100 mΩ, 1 % tolerance, 1 W. The INA with the best noise performance that I could find is the AD8429. There aren't that may 32-bit ADCs available, so the choice was easy (ADS1262). The power supply for the various components is purely LDO-based (to avoid the switching noise of switching regulators), and again I chose the LDOs with the best accuracy and lowest noise that I could find. The ADC's reference voltage (5 V) is also ultra-low noise.

**Test board**
I designed a PCB with the 100 mΩ sense resistor, the INA amplifying x28.2 (so output voltage 0 V - 4.25 V) and only one ADC sampling at 100 Hz. Looks like that:

[image]

Again, the supply/ground of the DUT and that of the current sensing circuit are isolated (the INA's supply isn't shown for simplicity). The 1 MΩ resistors are here to provide a path for the bias currents, but I'm not sure if the value is adapted.

At first glance, the system works fine, although the requirements aren't met (unsurprisingly). As a first test, I calibrated the INA+ADC chain (offset with shorted inputs, gain with a 1.5 A input current) and generated a current from 0.1 A to 1.5 A by 0.1 A steps through the measurement resistor. This current was also measured by a tabletop DMM (Agilent 3606) as a ground truth. For each current step, I recorded 100 samples of the ADC's output, synchronized with samples from the DMM (oversampled since it doesn't go as fast as the ADC).

**Result of the first test**
For each current step, for each of the 100 samples, I computed the absolute error \$|I_{DMM}-I_{ADC}|\$. Then took the average error over the 100 samples, to get one error per current step. Results are below.

[image]

It's not legible here but the error at 1.5 A is about 40 μA. The farther we get from 1.5 A, i.e. the calibration value, the worse the error. At 0.1 A input, the error is more than 20 % (5.4 mA). I think this is orders of magnitude larger than what could be explained by the ADC's nonlinearities. The INA isn't the problem, I measured its output voltage over the measurement range and the amplification is linear. I have no clue why the ADC becomes linearly less accurate for smaller input currents.

**Questions**
I have questions about the ADC's behavior but also about the system design in general, which I'm not satisfied with. I read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/188407/interfacing-current-shunt-monitor-with-16bit-adc) and I think I'm more or less in the same situation -- insufficient practical experience and unrealistic requirements.

1. Are the requirements too ambitious?
2. Is the 32-bit ADC overkill?
3. I have nearly zero practical experience of PCB design, all I know is
   self-taught. Getting a bunch of expensive components, throwing them
   on a beginner-level PCB and hoping that it's going to work fine is
   bad design practice, right?
4. Why is the ADC less accurate for smaller
   input? I'm starting to wonder if this calculation even makes sense,
   but now I'm stuck.

Comment: 1) Yes, unless you are doing fundemental particles physics at CERN or something. 2) I don't think that is even possible. A 24 bit ADC is already pushing the limit, the last 8 bits will only have noise (good random number source, though). 3) Can't really comment on that, but it sounds similar to hoisting a 200hp race engine into a Fiat Panda. 4) That one is easy: loss of resolution. If your voltage is so low that only a few bits of your ADC are used, you cannot make accurate measurements.

Comment: The accuracy for very small inputs is only a few bits. Consider doing a conversion to log (for the original signal). This yields better accuracy for small signals. This technique is used in audio - look up mu law and A law compression.

Comment: It seems to me that you have two distinct conditions you need to monitor: standby and on. The standby current should be constant and could be measured once using an inline meter. Design your logging system to just measure with adequate resolution for the high power situations and assume a constant background current.

Comment: Regarding the PCB question; maybe you could try getting an 'eval' kit for an ultra-precision amp -- not sure whats out there for the device you're currently using, but in the Maxim line, there is this one with 10kHz bandwidth: http://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/max9922-evaluation-kit/46607

At least gives you a benchmark circuit/layout to test performance against.

Comment: One thing you seemingly did not consider is that since you are averaging anyway, you can RC filter the output of the shunt to reduce the signal bandwidth enormously. Then you can just use a logging voltmeter to sample the signal. If your RC time constant is, say, 10 seconds, then the meter should be able to sample fast enough to closely approximate the average current.

Comment: Thanks all. @JvO 4) I don't understand that. I expected the error to be larger for small currents relatively to the measurement, but constant in absolute terms. What am I missing?

Comment: @jjmilburn Yes, that's what I'm going to do.

Comment: @mkeith The final product is supposed to sample at 1 kHz (with 10 ADCs) and no averaging. The averaging in this particular test was just to get the mean error.

Comment: I thought you were just trying to monitor total charge being removed from the battery. This whole thing is not making much sense to me. Is there some reason why you (or your clients) need to know instantaneous current other than to measure total cumulative battery drain?

Comment: @mkeith I think my boss wants to see what the current peaks look like (width and amplitude) when the tracker is transmitting. For info, it's my first project in this company and the device will stay inhouse. If it was up to me, I'd do what you suggested: use a logging voltmeter that we already have and just write a script to retrieve the measurements. Because I doubt that I can design better hardware than the Fluke people. But I don't know to what extent the project is really needed and what are just random requirements to see how good I'll do.

Comment: What if the peaks are less than 1ms? You may miss them altogehter with a 1ms sample period, and in any event you cannot measure their width very accurately. I think you need to at least RC filter the signal down to less than 500 Hz bandwidth.

Comment: Check out this project from Dave:
http://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/ Read the full article in pdf format:
http://alternatezone.com/electronics/ucurrent/uCurrentArticle.pdf It will give you some good ideas. Or else just buy their already made device ;-)

Comment: A- you have a path for bias through the load, and don't need the 1-megs.  B- an amp is a bunch of current, and your resistors may be heating up and may have different temp coefficients.

Comment: For future reference: 24bits is 16 million levels or 0.08uA for a 1.5A full scale input, now Linear has some 24bit adcs which can get to 1Msps at I think 18 or 19bits (you get more bits as you slow it down, to a maximum of I think 23bits at 4sps)

Comment: A 0.1 ohm sense resistor at 1μA is 100nV. At these levels you need to consider thermocouple effects which are measured in μV / degree C. One approach you could try is auto-ranging (which effectively changes the sense element as the input varies).

Comment: Instrumentation amplifiers like the one you are using have CMRR issues when run close to the rails.  In your case, when the currents are low, both input terminals are at the high rail (3.6 v).  You might try using a second battery for INA positive rail (be sure not to let the output voltage get above the adc max input voltage) so that your sense resistor is in the middle of the INA rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. Go back to your original goal of determining optimum fix interval. How is having ten 32-bit ADC in parallel vs. one 24-bit ADC going to affect your decision. Is your fix time in nano, micro or milliseconds? Most likely you don't need such ADC precision to get the optimal solution.

2) Yes. same as question 1. Look at the ADC you selected, at the desired 100SPS the intrinsic noise is 3.5 uVpp, this will probably not work at the low end of your range. So an auto-range or multi-range with average precision setup would be better that a single range with high precision.

3) To take advantage of 32-bits of resolution, the PCB layout will play an important role in minimizing noise but just looking at the component selection, you chose a 1% sensing resistor for instance with 0.1% ones readily available, I think you have other problems to consider.

4) This has been answered in the comments. While for high voltages the least-significant bits of the ADC are a small fraction of the conversion value, for tiny voltages these LSBs are significant.

For what is worth, on similar applications where long battery life is the final goal I have used Coulomb Counters (such as Linear's LTC4150) to measure the power consumed. Configure the system with different transmission times, let it run for some time and compare the total consumption for the period.